# Azure Devops queued builds with batch: true, get start to end commits

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to queue builds (avoid pipeline cancelation on new commit(s) push), my build tool acts as a "differential" build tool (you can provide one commit hash to build or you can provide a start commit hash to another one), I can not miss any build linked to any commit push, I would like to use "batch: true" but I did not find any way to have the start commit hash and the last commit hash of the batch (through ADO variables), this would allow me to forward it to my build tool, my build tool is mbt (https://github.com/mbtproject/mbt) and the feature I would like to exploit is https://github.com/mbtproject/mbt/blob/master/docs/mbt_describe_diff.md

Thanks for your help

I have no clue on how to find those two commit references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure Pipelines, there is no predefined variable to get all the commits for a build. The predefined variable "**`Build.SourceVersion`**" can only get the latest commit (last commit) for the build. No one can get the first commit (start commit). See "[**Use predefined variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services)".

To get both the last commit and the start commit, you need to call the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Builds - Get Build Changes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get-build-changes?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)". It will return all the commits for the specified build.

- Call the REST API to list all commits for the build.
- Pick up the ID of last commit and start commit from the response of REST API.
- Use the logging command '[**SetVariable**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable)' to set the commit ID as pipeline variables so that the subsequent steps in same job can use the values.

Below is an example as reference.

##### azure-pipelines.yml

```yaml
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - main

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Get commits'
      env:
        SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          response=$(curl -X GET -u :$SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/changes?api-version=7.0')
          count=$(echo $response | jq -r '.count')
          index=$((count-1))
          lastCommit=$(echo $response | jq -r '.value[0].id')
          startCommit=$(echo $response | jq --argjson index $index -r '.value[$index].id')
          echo "Build.SourceVersion = $(Build.SourceVersion)"
          echo "lastCommit = $lastCommit"
          echo "startCommit = $startCommit"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=lastCommit;]$lastCommit"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=startCommit;]$startCommit"
    
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Print variables'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          echo "lastCommit = $(lastCommit)"
          echo "startCommit = $(startCommit)"
```

##### Result

[image]